# Is there a way to control a popup window from the DevTools console of its parent's window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I click a button in the parent window programmatically by typing the code in DevTools console panel. This opens up a new window. Is their some way to click a button in this popup window using the console panel in the parent window?

I hope I was able to put my question clearly. :)

Comment: Depends on how the new window was opened. If it was opened as a result of a link using the `target` attribute, then no. If it was opened using javascript's [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), then maybe.

Comment: It was opened using JavaScript :)

Comment: Any chance you can provide code? Or a link to the site you're messing with? I ask because this sort of thing tends to be very specific to how it's implemented.

Comment: @Ouroborus I would like to avoid providing a link to the website directly in the comments. Can I give it to you in stackoverflow chat room? I don't know how to create a chat room though. :)

Comment: It depends. Sometimes it's possible to use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` (with credentials if needed) to manually parse the new window contents and do the button action without even opening the new window.